# Does Peppa Pig have a nationality, and if so what is it?

Tags: peppa-pig

I am interested in whether the eponymous Peppa Pig has a nationality. This is an in-universe question, which arose from a conversation with my children.

'Peppa Pig' seems to avoid directly assigning any concrete real-world geography to any of Peppa's adventures. The locations Peppa visits are usually generically named such as 'Windy Castle'.

This nation-less vision is disrupted by the movie 'Peppa Pig: My First Cinema Experience' where [Peppa Pig and her friends go to London and meet the Queen](https://www.theguardian.com/film/2017/apr/11/peppa-pig-my-first-cinema-experience).

In addition my children tell me they have seen an episode where Peppa visits Italy.

So it seems 'Peppa Pig' has a concrete geography after all. London and Italy are both in-universe locations.

In that case, what is Peppa's nationality?

Comment: Why would them visiting Italy change their nationality? I watched it growing up in the UK and I am 99% sure that they are British English. "Peppa Pig is a British preschool animated television series". The episode are 5 minutes long there is hardly going to be much lore...

Comment: @HenryM Thank you. I have improved my question, above. I am not saying that Peppa visiting Italy *changes* Peppa's nationality. I am saying that it suggests that she *has* a nationality in-universe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### There is a constructive ambiguity about the relationship between Peppa's world and the real world, which gradually crystallizes

Early examples of Peppa Pig geography include the generically named 'Windy Castle'. However, later episodes crystallize the Peppa Pig universe's relationship with our geography.

Series 5 Episode 15 '[London](http://peppapig.wikia.com/wiki/Episodes)' features a trip by coach to London and a visit to meet the Queen. Other encounters with The Queen occur in episodes 'The Queen' and the movie 'Peppa Pig: My First Cinema Experience'.

Series 8 Episode 4 '[International Day](http://peppapig.wikia.com/wiki/International_Day)' acknowledges the nations of France,
Russia, America, Japan, Holland, South Africa, Germany, Switzerland, Mexico, Australia, United Kingdom, Spain and Greece. There is no direct indication which is the home nation.

Other answers here have pointed out that Peppa can reach London without boarding a plane. Indications therefore of Peppa being of British nationality are **strong**.

*However*, these 'nationalities' are only analogous to the real-world, just as the city of London in 'Peppa Pig' and the character of the Queen are all analogues to the real thing.

Answer (score 6):

Peppa is a resident in a commonwealth nation.  This is demonstrated as the Queen presents Miss Rabbit with a medal for being the hardest working person in the country, and calls a national holiday.

It is reasonable to assume that the country is in mainland UK as they travel by bus to London, and in cases where they travel to other countries they are seen to be flying.

Regarding whether Nationality is a valid concept in the program - yes, it is introduced in season 2. It is not relevant to Peppa's world view until she meets Delphine Donkey, after which she consistently refers to her as 'my French friend'. Subsequently she makes friends with children from various other nations, such as Gabriella Goat from Italy and Kylie Kangaroo from Australia.

Comment: +1 I really like this evidential answer - many thanks. Do the events you mention take place in the movie? I confess I haven't seen it...

Comment: The medal episode predates the film, iirc part of the premise of the film is to visit Miss Rabbit's friend - the Queen.

Answer (score 2):

Peppa and her family visited Italy in vacations and they were back to their home country at the end of the vacations. As Henry mentioned above, visiting a foreign country does not change nationality !!

As [Peppa Pig Fanon Wiki](https://peppafanon.wikia.com/wiki/Peppa_Pig_(character)) states,

> ```
> Nationality :English
>              Peppish (Eggs)
> ```

So, she is English as far as our geographical boundaries work, and it is Peppish in the pig world I guess.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me to this extraordinary fan-fiction wiki. However, the wiki merely asserts that Peppa is English, and does not offer any supporting evidence or argumentation.